# Trying to sort names by length

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bufferedreader, string-length

I am trying to read a list of 5 names off a file, determine the length of each name and sort the lengths using an array. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to pass the length of the name to the array... Help is very much appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
    FileNotFoundException {

String file = "names.txt";
processFile("names.txt");

}


public static void processFile (String file) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
BufferedReader inputReader =
       new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader
(new FileInputStream("names.txt")));
String line;
while  (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null){

   int nameL =line.length();

} 
/*public static void main (String [] args) {
*/
    int [] aryNum;
    aryNum= new int [5];

    aryNum[0] = int nameL;
    aryNum[1]=int nameL;
    aryNum[2]=int nameL;
    aryNum[3]=int nameL;
    aryNum[4]=nameL;

   Arrays.sort(aryNum);

   int i;

   for (i=0; i<aryNum.length; i++) {
       System.out.println("" + aryNum[i]);

   }

}


}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort just the lengths of names or do you want to sort the names (strings) based on their lengths?

Comment: I would like to sort the lengths of the names, but learning how to sort the names based on their lengths would also be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the lengths of the strings in an array, then you are really looking to sort the numbers:

```
static int[] getSortedLengths(String[] names) {
    int len = names.length;
    int [] lengths = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // watch for nulls
        lengths[i] = names[i].length();
    }
    Arrays.sort(lengths);
    return lengths;
}
```

If you want to sort the names (which are strings), you use the generic concept of sorting based on a comparator. A comparator implements a *behavior* that orders elements of a collection (or array) by certain criterion. The interesting part is you just need to abstract out the comparison of two elements of the type that your collection (or array) is made of. Then you pass the comparator to the sorting method and voila! you get a sorted collection (or array). For starters, let's use the following version:

```
static void sortStringsByLength(String[] names) {
    Comparator<String> stringLengthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
        }
    };
    Arrays.sort(names, stringLengthComparator);
}
```

Just by playing with the `compare` method, you can do many things like reverse ordering all the strings by length (longest string first), or sorting them by some kind of score for each string and so on. This is called *abstraction*, a skill of paramount importance in computer programming.

Comment: Thanks so much! How do I incorporate this into my code though? When I try I get errors such as "Illegal start of expression" and "cannot find class"...

Comment: I think you have some basic code organization issues. Start by downloading an IDE like [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) and then coding the methods one by one: read a file line by line and adding those lines (supposedly names) to a predefined array. The code you posted above does not look like something that compiles. Post separate questions with clear error messages you get. That, however, should not stop you from accepting my answer above :-).